# How to force latexrun to parallel build?

Tags: compiling, tools, build-system

I have a series of independent documents belonging to the same thing, each having its own main tex file. I wrote a small Makefile to wrap latexrun. latexrun is fantastic, but if I try to build all the pdfs in parallel (e.g. by calling `make -j`), the separate latexrun instances all start sequentially. I tried this outside make with:

```
for f in *.tex; do latexrun -Wall -O .build/ "$f" & true; done
#          this should make it run in parallel ---^
```

And again they refuse to run in parallel. Why is that and how do I fix this?

Comment: and what exactly is `latexrun`? and what OS are you running on?

Comment: I'm running debian/sid and latexrun is just off-hand the best latex compiler (except that it currently refuses to run in parallel). See https://github.com/aclements/latexrun

Comment: I'm not sure if this question might rather belong on SO proper.

Comment: Can't say what you are doing wrong. I probably would not just run say 100 processes in the background, but rather in batches, for example via gnu parallels. And I agree this is not a LaTeX question.

Comment: Never mind, I found the solution by looking at the debug output of latexrun. See answer.

Answer (score 2):

After examining the build directory, it seems that latexrun locks its database while running. So giving each file its own directory fixes this problem as each latexrun instance has its separate database for each file to be built.

This is an excerpt from the Makefile

```
B:=.build
S:=$(wildcard *.tex)
T:=$(S:.tex=.pdf)

.PHONY: all
all: $T

$T: %.pdf: %.tex $(wildcard include/*)
    @mkdir -p '$B/$(patsubst %.tex,%,$<)/'
    @./.latexrun -Wall -O '$B/$(patsubst %.tex,%,$<)/' --color always '$<'
    @cp '$B/$(patsubst %.tex,%,$<)/$@' '$@'
```

This builds file1.tex in .build/file1/file1.pdf and file2.tex in .build/file2/file2.pdf and then copies the to the main directory.

**In this case this reduces build time from 23.5s to 5.8s.**

Comment: What exactly does `database` mean in this context?

Comment: @daleif Basically latexrun creates `.latexrun.db` and `.latexrun.db.lock` in its build directory. These interfere if several instances are running in the same build directory.

Comment: That is probably why latexmk creates its version as a suffix to the main filename instead, thus avoiding that issue. Note that you really need to trust a tool that parses the log output and only shows you important stuff. We have seen time and time again that they get it wrong, or copy the wrong context to show to the user.

Comment: Honestly, plain latex is broken regarding the mess it calls output. It is not usable and I used to constantly overlook warnings.

Comment: That is just because you're not used to it. I generally use `latexmk -pvc` that just runs in a terminal behind my editor. Plus I use `-halt-on-error`, so that is not an issue. The main thing IMO is that users have a tendency to ignore warnings and thus they pile up.

Comment: Well, I use latex a lot and for well over ten years. I'm still not comfortable parsing the output. I guarantee that I miss more than any remotely sensible tool might miss. And I think this goes for a majority of people.

Comment: Going on 20+ years for me. I also never understood those who insit on using build dirs and getting aux files etc out of the way.